# How to implement countdown timer which can be paused when power goes off or web page is closed?

Tags: c#, timer

Remaining time in seconds will be stored in database as `float` (miliseconds will be calculated too)

My timer tick will decrease seconds(including miliseconds) depending on how much time is passed between last call and current call

Implementation with .txt as storage looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Session["syncCountdownTimer"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        timerCountdown.Enabled = true;
        timerCountdown.Interval = 1000;
    }
    DecreaseSeconds();
}

protected void timerCountdown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DecreaseSeconds();
}

private void DecreaseSeconds()
{
    double seconds = GetCountdown();
    String testSync = Session["syncCountdownTimer"].ToString();
    Session["syncCountdownTimer"] = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime syncLastDateTime = DateTime.Parse(testSync);
    TimeSpan substructed = DateTime.Now.Subtract(syncLastDateTime);
    double syncSeconds = substructed.TotalSeconds;

    seconds -= syncSeconds;

    int hour = (int)seconds / 3600;
    int min = (int)seconds % 3600 / 60;
    int sec = (int)seconds % 3600 % 60;

    lblCountdownStatus.Text = (hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : "" + hour) + ":" +
                              (min < 10 ? "0" + min : "" + min) + ":" +
                              (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : "" + sec);
    SetCountdown(seconds);
}

private double GetCountdown()
{
    string filename = @"D:\countdown.txt";
    TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);
    double seconds = double.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
    reader.Close();
    return seconds;
}

private void SetCountdown(double seconds)
{
    string filename = @"D:\countdown.txt";
    TextWriter writter = File.CreateText(filename);
    writter.WriteLine(seconds);
    writter.Close();
}
```

Final implementation requires:

- making sure of connection latency
- security(timer ticks won't be changed to be gained more time for the quiz)
- when browser is closed or suddenly power goes off, the player time should be stopped

Any other ideas are welcome

Answer (score 0):

The time decrement should be implemented at the server-side. Each decrement at the server should be accompanied by a database update. In that way, if the web page is closed and reopened, the next decrement will continue from where it stopped.The JS below is the client-side script that will call the server handler and update the UX.

JS:

```
setTimeout(decrementTime, 1000);
function decrementTime() {
  // call Server
}
function decrementTimeCallback() {
   // updateUIWithServerTime
}
```

Comment: What if there are delays in the connecting?